# When will Ios VoIP PushKit token get updated

Tags: ios, swift, apn, pushkit

My app is using both user notification token and PushKit token.
I have managed to get both the tokens and saved them in my server. However, when i uninstall and reinstall my mobile app, APN only update my user notification token but not PushKit token.
Is this the default behaviour from Apple?
I am expecting APN to update both the tokens whenever I reinstall my app.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679986
This is the link for the similar question posted by others and the response from Apple was the PushKit token should also be updated upon reinstalling the app

Answer (score 1):

After so many tries on uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the Pushkit token seems to only changed when I download the new app from test flight. It is the same case for test flight build. Despite giving a different Pushkit token, it wont refresh even if i reinstall the app.

The workaround for this issue that I figured out was to append my server token to the payload of the notification and compare it with the current logged in session token.